# String as Entity ID inserted by user [EclipseLink]

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, derby

### **[INTRO]**

1. Database : Apache Derby
2. JPA : EclipseLink

Hey, I was looking for answer but couldn't find any so here it goes. I'm writing simple sudoku app, and the next feature which I would like to add is saving my Sudoku boards in database, and retrieve them when it's needed. Here is UML diagram of my main two classes:
[SudokuBoard.uml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTsq8.jpg)
The structure of my two entities are as follows :

The SudokuBoard entity:

```
@Entity
public class SudokuBoard implements Serializable, Cloneable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private ArrayList<SudokuField> board;

public ArrayList<SudokuField> board() {
    return board;
}

public void setBoard(ArrayList<SudokuField> board) {
    this.board= board;
}

public Long etId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

The SudokuField entity:

```
@Entity
public class SudokuField implements Serializable, Comparable<SudokuField>, 
Cloneable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Transient
private static final Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(SudokuField.class);
@Transient
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Column(name = "Value")
private int value;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "board_fk", referencedColumnName = "id")
private SudokuBoard sudokuBoard;
```

The execution in DAO:

```
@Override
public void write(SudokuBoard obj, String path) throws 
FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(obj);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

**[PROBLEM]**

1. I wonder if there is any possiblity to not use auto generated key but instead use String as PK in SudokuBoard entity. In my application I implemented binding so I would like to save the same object of SudokuBoard which is changing over time under different names.

Hope I stated my intentions clearly. Thanks for any help and tips how it could be done.

Answer (score 1):

Using `String` as primary key is straightforward - just declare it as such and drop the `@GeneratedValue` annotation.

However, changing the primary key (if that's what you mean by 'saving the same object (...) under different names') is not possible. If you try to `persist/merge` an existing entity under a different primary key, JPA will either raise an exception or treat it as a new entity, resulting in duplicate entries in the database. Simply put, assigning id to an entity is permanent.

All in all, I'd suggest you keep an autogenerated surrogate key and declare another unique `String` field for the name. Conveying business information using technical fields is rarely a good idea.

Comment: By  'saving the same object (...) under different names' I meant I'd like to have multiple entries of the same object which state is different over the time. Also now when I instantiate the object, I can't persist it multiple times as its PK is assigned only once and duplicate key exception is thrown whenever I try to do this.  The concept which I would like to implement is :
1) Create random sudoku field
2) Save it to database
3) Fill some of the missing fields of the same board
4) Be able to save it again under different ID

Comment: OK, now I get it. Unfortunately, I don't think there's an easy way to implement what you want other than manually creating and saving a copy of `SudokuBoard` **and** `SudokuField`s. Don't you think your data model is a little overcomplicated? Do `SudokuField`s really need a persistent identity of their own? I'd suggest using an integer list. If you absolutely need a separate `SudokuField` model, I'd still swap the `@OneToMany` mapping for an `@ElementCollection` of `@Embeddable`s.

Comment: This way, instead of copying the entire structure manually, you will be able to `detach` the `Sudokuboard`, update the primary key, and `persist` it as a new entity. Providing new copies for the list of `SudokuField`s will no longer be necessary.

Comment: doing so, I will be able to store multiple boards within database or just the most actual one ? Will try to implement that. Thanks for support and brief explaining

Comment: Typically, you `merge` a detached entity while preserving the original id to 'show' the entity manager what state you would now expect it to have. However, when you change the id and then `persist` a detached entity instead, it will be treated as completely new. This operation will not affect the original entity in any way, so you will end up with two entities instead of one.